# Azure outbound traffic is being blocked

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-load-balancer, azure-nsg

I have setup a few VM's and a load balancer so that we can have one outgoing IP. Right now i am having issues to connect to the internet from inside my VM. If i open internet explorer and try to access a website, it shows waiting for reply and then "This page can’t be displayed".

Each VM is connected to the same subnet.

[image]

The subnet has a NSG attached to it and each VM is part of the subnet.
[image]
NSG attached to the subnet.
[image]
[image]
[image]

There is then a load balancer to allow incoming RDP but with different ports to the different VM's.

[image]

I think i am missing the SNAT but i have no idea where to configure that. From what i have read, i am using level 2 "Public Load Balancer associated with a VM (no Instance Level Public IP address on the instance)". Multiple VM's on a subnet and one load balancer to share one IP address.

Where do i actually go to set up the SNAT? Or is there another issue i am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you could add the `load balancing rules` for TCP port 80 or 443 instead of inbound NAT rules. NAT rules always use for port forwarding. Moreover, you do not need add NAT rules for DNS. This works on my side.

A [load balancer rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/tutorial-load-balancer-port-forwarding-portal#create-a-load-balancer-rule) defines how traffic is distributed to the VMs. The rule defines the front-end IP configuration for incoming traffic, the back-end IP pool to receive the traffic, and the required source and destination ports.

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm. I understood the load balancing rules as decision rules for incoming traffic, like if the same VM should receive the traffic from a specific user, a round robin or another type of system. 
Thanks.